# How to loop Array combine 2 For with 1 If

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I just learned how to use Array to combine 2 For with 1 If and was trying to write the following, but I got an error. Thanks for help the wrong place.
Error: compile error duplicate declaration in current scope

```
Dim arr1 As Variant, i  Dim arr2 As Variant, x  arr1 = Array("A1","A2","A100") arr2 = Array("B1","B2","B100")
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase(arr1(i))) And InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), LCase(arr2(x))) Then
            Run function1
            Exit For
        End If
     Next 
Next
```

Comment: What error did you get? On which row?

Comment: I added error content.

Comment: so on which row compile error lol?

Comment: Duplicate declaration means you've used `Dim` on the same name twice within the script. Double check each of your `Dim` lines to make sure they aren't repeating the names.

Comment: I fixed my issue, Toddleson :)